# Define common styles in android drawables

Tags: android, styles, drawable

I am trying to style a list item in android. I am using the following xml drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#882980b9"></solid>
                <corners android:radius="@dimen/margin"></corners>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:bottom="2dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@android:color/white"></solid>
                <corners android:radius="@dimen/margin"></corners>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#333498db"></solid>
                <corners android:radius="@dimen/margin"></corners>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
  </item>
  <item>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#bdc3c7"></solid>
                <corners android:radius="@dimen/margin"></corners>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:bottom="2dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@android:color/white"></solid>
                <corners android:radius="@dimen/margin"></corners>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
  </item>
</selector>
```

As you can see there are some elements that are repetitive. Is there a way to pull out common shapes so that they are available in both states, such that they have to be updated only at one place? Something like we do in css?

```
.normal {
    /* common styles */
}
.normal:hover {
    /* only overriding/extra styles */
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the shape drawables into separate files and reference from your layer list items.

There's an android:drawable="" attribute on item.

See here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList